# Why http cookies are not removed even when expiration time is already hit

Tags: javascript, cookies

I came across a strange problem, i am setting the cookies in chrome with the help of following javaScript code. i have set the expires property for 'Name' cookie and max-age property for 'Age' cookie, but none of them are working as cookies are not removed even when the specified time is already passed away. can you please explain me why?

```
document.cookie = "Name=Max; expires=Tue, 22 June 2021 10:36:11";
document.cookie = "Age=31; max-age=100000";
```

Comment: You forgot the time zone identifier (`GMT`). Perhaps your browser is handling it as local time zone (I can't tell for sure).

Comment: thanks men, finally i have figured out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The expiry date should be set in the UTC/GMT format. If you do not set the expiry date, the cookie will be removed when the user closes the browser.

Comment: Haven't i done that already? can you please show me what i have to change over here.

Comment: document.cookie = "Name=Max; expires=Tue, 22 June 2021 10:36:11 **GMT**"; 
or
document.cookie = "cookiename=cookievalue; expires= Thu, 21 Aug 2014 20:00:00 **UTC**"